# PDO data types does not enforce the type casting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem or misunderstanding of PDO data binding especially bindValue() method,
I have searched a lot but I haven't found my answer yet.

here is the example,

```
global $connection;

$name = 22;

$stm = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET `name` = :name");

$stm->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($stm->execute()) {
    echo 'Done';
}
```

And then, the execution is done, the value is stored in the database as an integer number, not a string and no error appears.

Comment: what type of column is `name` ? It suggests it is a string. A string can consist of any character. Also numeric characters. In php it is quite hard to tell the difference between 1 and "1"

Comment: Does it work? If so, what's the issue?

Comment: It would only be stored as an integer if the type of `name` column is an integer, otherwise it would be stored a string.

Comment: the column type is varchar and the issue is that why the execution done successfully while i passed an "Integer" number, and as you see i told the ":name" must be a string,

another point, when i passed a string like this ' OR '1'='1' => it accepted it too ... why?

Comment: Because '1' is a valid `varchar`, and the database can store *not only letters* in a `varchar`, but any *characters* (that are representable in the encoding used by the column; if you use utf8mb4, you can probably store *emojis*).

Comment: isn't that bad characters that my cause a sql injection??

Comment: They don't, not with prepared statements using placeholder values. That will insert the literal value `OR '1'='1'` which is just junk text as far as the database is concerned. They would if that was just substituted into the query, that's the definition of "injection", but placeholder values work differently. The data is often sent separately over to MySQL and assembled properly on the server.

Comment: Ok, i got it thank you all very much for your time..

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think so, please at first try that at your browser frst:

```
$name = '22';
echo $name;
var_dump($name);
```

as you see eventought he echoOut 22 as an integer but it's type is a string.
PHP handled this in the recent versions, If you tried to add some number to the $name variable it will goes fine, Eventhought the variable is string!

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this same issue, and yes this particular example is flawed because the `$name = 22;` will go into a varchar field without issue.

So my example is I have a field that is defined in the db as an Integer, and I have an int but it is sometimes passed as a string e.g. `'1'` and even though I'm binding param with `\PDO::PARAM_INT` it still throws errors about implicit conversion.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM randTable WHERE intField = :numnum");
$pdo->execute($stmt, [':numnum', '1', \PDO::PARAM_INT]);
```

I would expect this to enforce the injected string as an int...but it does not. If anyone knows why this is it would also explain the issue asked here. If you could send me details as to why it doesn't work that would be much appreciated!

So what we had to do was to enforce our type in the query itself and could do this here as well:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM randTable WHERE intField = CONVERT(int, :numnum"));
$pdo->execute($stmt, [':numnum', '1', \PDO::PARAM_INT]);
```

I don't like this...but it works.

FYI I'm using a **Sybase** database.

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: We are currently using Sybase but in the process of changing to MS SQL.

Comment: I would advise to state it in the answer, as the question is tagged with mysql and your answer could confuse people using this database.